# ImageIO: <ERROR> JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment iphone - how to catch this?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimage, javax.imageio

I get this error by downloading an image by HTTP. I have looked at the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788138/how-to-get-errors-warnings-in-uiimage-initwithdata) but even the valid images don't return `YES` from the function.

Any other ideas?

The code to get the image is simple enough.  This happens in a background thread.

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

This is the function from that thread:

```
- (BOOL)isJPEGValid:(NSData *)jpeg {
    if ([jpeg length] < 4) return NO;
    const char * bytes = (const char *)[jpeg bytes];
    if (bytes[0] != 0xFF || bytes[1] != 0xD8) return NO;
    if (bytes[[jpeg length] - 2] != 0xFF || 
            bytes[[jpeg length] - 1] != 0xD9) return NO;
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use an unsigned char. Then comparing should work.

```
const unsigned char * bytes = (const unsigned char *)[jpeg bytes];
```

instead of

```
const char * bytes = (const char *)[jpeg bytes];
```

Comment: It still shows the error: <Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment. :(