# ERROR Corrupt JPEG dataCorrupt JPEG data When Download Image From Server

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

I am using an `Server` to Crop `Image` and client will request and get `image` from `sever` but when app run system get an warning with an error

`<Error>: ImageIO: JPEG Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment`

help me!!!!!!

Comment: where is code and its depends how you reading check this too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1064920/iphone-corrupt-jpeg-data-for-image-received-over-http

Comment: You can have a look on these similar ones too:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6788138/how-to-get-errors-warnings-in-uiimage-initwithdata

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848280/catching-error-corrupt-jpeg-data-premature-end-of-data-segment