# AFImageRequestOperation returns image that not downloaded competely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

```
+[AFImageRequestOperation imageRequestOperationWithRequest:
                                      imageProcessingBlock:
                                                   success:
                                                   failure:]
```

In case of slow internet returns image (PNG particularly) that didn't download completely and failure block, in this situation, is not being called.

How can I check that the image did or didn't download correctly?

**Edit:** It doesn't really matter what type of request you will have: image, xml, json or http, there are a probability that file downloading will fail. And as file becomes bigger and internet becomes slower the probability increases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial solution founded in this questions:
[Catching error: Corrupt JPEG data: premature end of data segment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3848280/catching-error-corrupt-jpeg-data-premature-end-of-data-segment?lq=1)
[Detect if PNG file is corrupted in Objective C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552145/detect-if-png-file-is-corrupted-in-objective-c/12726493#12726493)

So, after image was downloaded, you can check does it have correct starting and ending bytes.

**Edit:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13221274/1052237) is a more flexible solution.