# How to know if a UIImage is representable in PNG or JPG?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage

I got a `UIImage` from `UIImagePickerController`, and using the code from [this site](http://vocaro.com/trevor/blog/2009/10/12/resize-a-uiimage-the-right-way/) to resize the image

```
- (UIImage *)resizedImage:(CGSize)newSize
                transform:(CGAffineTransform)transform
           drawTransposed:(BOOL)transpose
     interpolationQuality:(CGInterpolationQuality)quality {
    CGRect newRect = CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height));
    CGRect transposedRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, newRect.size.height, newRect.size.width);
    CGImageRef imageRef = self.CGImage;

    // Build a context that's the same dimensions as the new size
    CGContextRef bitmap = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                                newRect.size.width,
                                                newRect.size.height,
                                                CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(imageRef),
                                                0,
                                                CGImageGetColorSpace(imageRef),
                                                CGImageGetBitmapInfo(imageRef));

    // Rotate and/or flip the image if required by its orientation
    CGContextConcatCTM(bitmap, transform);

    // Set the quality level to use when rescaling
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(bitmap, quality);

    // Draw into the context; this scales the image
    CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, transpose ? transposedRect : newRect, imageRef);

    // Get the resized image from the context and a UIImage
    CGImageRef newImageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(bitmap);
    UIImage *newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:newImageRef];

    // Clean up
    CGContextRelease(bitmap);
    CGImageRelease(newImageRef);

    return newImage;
}
```

`UIImagePNGRepresentation()` failed to return `NSData` on re-sized image, but `UIImageJPEGRepresentation()` succeed.

How do we know if a `UIImage` is presentable in PNG or JPEG? What missed in the above code that make the resized image can not be represented in PNG?

According to apple document: "This function may return nil if the image has no data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported bitmap format."

What bitmap format supported by PNG presentation? How to make an UIImage PNG-supported format?

Comment: What is the color / pixel format of the image that failed?

Comment: I didn't talking about] a specific color component or pixel of the image. I meant UIImagePNGRepresentation(resultimage) return nil

Comment: I am asking about the color / pixel format of your CGContextRef.  That is the only reason I can think of for UIPNGRepresentation to fail (unsupported color format / pixel format).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check if downloaded PNG image is corrupt?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152616/how-to-check-if-downloaded-png-image-is-corrupt)

Comment: @borrrden you 're right, the image create by CGBitmapContextCreate with kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was a mistake that in another part of the code the image was rescaled with the following

```
CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL,
                                         size.width,
                                         size.height,
                                         8,
                                         0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(source),
                                         kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst);
```

Changing kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipFirst to CGImageGetBitmapInfo(source) fixed the problem

Answer (score -1):

go to following link...

[How to check if downloaded PNG image is corrupt?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13152616/how-to-check-if-downloaded-png-image-is-corrupt)

it may help you...

Let me know it is working or not...

Happy Coding!!!!

Comment: Link only answers aren't very helpful in the long run. And if you're just linking to an SO answer it's probably better to just mark the question as a duplicate.