# JavaFX: Get format (PNG, JPG..) of an image?

Tags: java, image, png, javafx-2, image-formats

I am creating an application that for some reasons shall only accept PNG images.

How can I check if an image is really a PNG image? Currently I am using the JavaFX 2 [Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/index.html?javafx/scene/image/Image.html) class to load the image.

Thanks for any hint!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do this currently in my own application by confirming the file's Mime Type before I process it. There are several SO threads suggesting how to obtain Mime Types in Java.

- [Getting A File's Mime Type In Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java)
- [java library to find the mime type from file content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4348810/java-library-to-find-the-mime-type-from-file-content)

Comment: I ended up Chris Mowforth's answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51438/getting-a-files-mime-type-in-java: Java 7's Files.probeContentType(path) - works great in my case. So thanks for the hint :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't trust the filename, a simple check is to read the first 8 bytes  (with `FileInputStream`), and check that they correspond to the PNG signature (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10555053/277304)

Comment: That would be checking a mime type.

Comment: Thank you too! There's a handy way in Java 7, see my comment to Josh's reply.