# Avoid Caching HTTP(S) Requests/Responses- How to disable CachePolicy in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: xamarin.ios

How do we disable caching policy in xamarin ios. I have referred to the following links .

https://github.com/nowsecure/secure-mobile-development/blob/master/en/ios/avoid-caching-https-requests-responses.md

[NSURLConnection Delegate Returns Null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30667340/nsurlconnection-delegate-returns-null)

Please let me know the equivalent code in c # (Xamarin.iOS)

Can we add something in info.plist?

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 7+ we begin to use [NSUrlSession](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/MonoTouch.Foundation.NSUrlSession/) to handle web task instead of NSUrlConnection. Then you can try below code to disable the cache:

```
NSUrlSessionConfiguration configure = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
configure.RequestCachePolicy = NSUrlRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData;
configure.URLCache = null;

NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(configure);
```

Comment: Hi Land Lu , Thanks! Where should we add the above code in  Appdelegate (Any method in AppDelegate ) or anywhere ?

Comment: When you want to use this session to download data.